# Reactivate a disabled submit button by going to the previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Here is the js code I am using at the moment to disable a submit button :

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $(':submit').html('submitting').addClass('disabled');
});
```

The problem is if the user goes back after submitting the form, the button will already be disabled. I tried a lot of "hacks" but the js doesn't seem to be reloaded by going back to the previous page (with the "previous" of the browser).

Do you have an idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks !!

Comment: You can write code for enabling the button on page load .

Comment: The problem is, methods "load" or "ready" are not called by a browser "previous page" button

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same problem, here is ONE OF THE SOLUTIONS :

```
$(window).on('unload', function () {});
```